# Insert query results into different fields in a table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

I need to insert a query result into a table, but in a way that my different rows will be inserted into different fields. I tried:

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination (Rec1, Rec2)
SELECT TOP 2 ID FROM tblOrigin;
```

I am not surprised this does not work, but I am out of ideas. Is there a way to achieve the same result? I am using MS Access

EDIT:

```
 Name                                                  Type                        Size
     ID                                                    Long Integer                             4
     SSN                                                   Text                                   255
     Filedat                                               Date/Time                                8
     Firstnam                                              Text                                   186
     MI                                                    Text                                   255
     Lastnam                                               Text                                   255
     Sfirstnam                                             Text                                   255
     Slastnam                                              Text                                   255
     Streetadd                                             Text                                   255
     Acity                                                 Text                                   255
     Astate                                                Text                                     2
     Azipcode                                              Text                                   255
     Dob                                                   Date/Time                                8
     Madd                                                  Text                                   255
     Mcity                                                 Text                                   255
     Mstate                                                Text                                   255
     mzip                                                  Text                                   255
     Tele                                                  Text                                   255
     MobileH                                               Yes/No                                   1
     aHome                                                 Yes/No                                   1
     Livenvcont                                            Yes/No                                   1
     Ownothprop                                            Yes/No                                   1
     Othpropcnty                                           Text                                     2
     Othpropstate                                          Text                                    30
     Othpropparcel                                         Text                                   255
     Otassedval                                            Currency                                 8
     Busrentaluse                                          Text                                   255
     Anylivwith                                            Yes/No                                   1
     Numliving                                             Long Integer                             4
     Inctax                                                Yes/No                                   1
     DOD                                                   Date/Time                                8
     Proofdob                                              Yes/No                                   1
     Ssnprof                                               Yes/No                                   1
     W21099sub                                             Yes/No                                   1
     Valliqidas                                            Yes/No                                   1
     CreditReport                                          Yes/No                                   1
     Parcelnum                                             Text                                   255
     Mobilehomenum                                         Text                                   255
     Assval                                                Currency                                 8
     Datrec                                                Date/Time                                8
     Countyp                                               Text                                   255
     Tasdist                                               Text                                   255
     Acttaxpd                                              Currency                                 8
     Pssinc                                                Currency                                 8
     Pssi                                                  Currency                                 8
     Ppension                                              Currency                                 8
     Pint                                                  Currency                                 8
     Pcapg                                                 Currency                                 8
     pwage                                                 Currency                                 8
     prent                                                 Currency                                 8
     Paligam                                               Currency                                 8
     Othinc                                                Currency                                 8
     Totinc                                                Currency                                 8
     Totcashval                                            Currency                                 8
     Ssocial                                               Currency                                 8
     Sssi                                                  Currency                                 8
     Spension                                              Currency                                 8
     swage                                                 Currency                                 8
     Notes                                                 Memo                                     -
     Approved                                              Date/Time                                8
```

The only required fields are Filedat, Firstnam, Lastnam.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able. I am handling HIPPA-classified data... I can describe it, if it helps. For this part of the job I really just need to store the record IDs for some of the records that were included in a manual process, which happens externally to the database. I would need this information as  form of tracking.

Comment: Ok, can you possibly create some fake data instead only a few rows would be necessary.

Comment: Sure. I will create an edit.

Comment: Dude, apologies, there is no way to make that look good. BTW I am not responsible for those field names, I wanted to make that very clear.

Comment: Can you provide the Table DDL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)

Comment: I'm trying to help you but I need you to help me with your data too are you provideing a value for each and every column?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Definitely not providing a value per field. This is a humongous table, however I only need to extract and save certain IDs for a log. I have really complicated query that determines with individuals require a certain action, which will happen 20 at a time, and I need to store those IDs in a log with the date and some more information regarding the procedure, which happens outside of the database.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a `join` or something like that.  For your example, aggregation will work:

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination (Rec1, Rec2)
    SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id)
    FROM (SELECT TOP 2 ID
          FROM tblOrigin
         ) as o;
```

Comment: Ahah! That is clever. My actual task involves 20 fields, but aggregation seems to be a good way to transpose the fields like I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO tblDestination (Rec1, Rec2)
SELECT TOP 2 ID FROM tblOrigin;

You are telling it to insert 2 field then only supplying one.

INSERT INTO tblDestination ([ColumToInsertInto])
SELECT TOP 2 ID FROM tblOrigin;

Comment: I need the information returned from the same field/column in the origin table to be entered in different fields at the destination.